# Finding a specific record in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.6

I'm making a project for school where users are quizzed on subjects and their results are saved into a report (CSV file called 'reportForFergusTwo') for the 'customer' (Fergus). The report shows the average score a certain quiz, the high score, and the username of the person who achieved it. And then, I'm meant to display the user's details but the user's details are saved in a different CSV file ('details').

So far I've made a function that finds the highest score and username of the person who achieved it in the CSV 'reportForFergusTwo'. I now need to work on a function that searches through another CSV file ('details').

```
def findHighScoreUser():
    print(user)
    with open ('details.csv', 'r') as stalking:
        stalkingReader=csv.reader(stalking)
        valid4=False
        for row in stalkingReader:
            if user in row:
                valid4=True
                print("Here are the details for user {}... ".format(user))
                splitter=row.split(',')
                name=splitter[0]
                age=splitter[1]
                year=splitter[2]
                print("Name: {}".format(name))
                print("Age: {}".format(age))
                print("Year Group: {}".format(year))
                postReport()
    if valid4==False:
        print("Sorry Fergus, this user doesn't seem to be in our records.")
```

'user' is a variable from my previous function, where I found the username of the person with the highest score. It holds the username. I made it global and printed it at the start of this function, and that's working, making me think this is an issue I've made in reading the CSV.

Here is the details CSV:

```
Name,Age,Year Group,Username,Password
Erin Jones,15,11,Eri15,Password
Lucas Jones,16,11,Luc16,Password2
Michael Jordan,11,7,Mic11,GetSomeHelp
La Roux,14,9,La 14,Bulletproof
```

And here is the reportForFergusTwo CSV:

```
Subject,Difficulty,Score,Username
language,easy,10,Luc16
chemistry,easy,10,Luc16
maths,easy,9,Luc16
chemistry,easy,5,Eri15
chemistry,easy,6,Mic11
chemistry,easy,0,Eri15
```

I'm still fairly new to code, so please excuse me if the answer is obvious.

Comment: The whole point of the `csv` module is that you *don't* have to split the lines yourself. If you are using `.split()`, your are doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was told to use .split() when asking for help, thank you for pointing this out. Any suggestions on what to do instead?

Comment: The CSV reader will split the row for you when you give it the right parameters. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader You might also give the DictReader a try. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: It's actually a bad thing to use `.split` on CSV, since this is perfectly valid in CSV: `val1,val2,"val3,right here"` - this has 3 values, the third one contains a comma. The csv module would do the right thing, `.split(',')` would mess this up. Avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user is no longer in scope you can provide it to your function like this:

```
def functionThatFindsHighestScoreUser():
    # do stuff
    return maxScoreUser 

def findHighScoreUser(user):
    print(user)
    # the rest of your existing code

# get the user
maxScoreUser = functionThatFindsHighestScoreUser()

# find it and print details
findHighScoreUser(maxScoreUser)
```

There is almost always a way around global variables by using parameters in the function - don't use them, provide each function exactly with what it needs.

---

As for the csv-issues: csv module does the splitting for you as Tomalak mentioned. You can consume the reader line wise and get a list of all fields:

```
import csv


def checkUsers(name):
    with open("users.csv",encoding="utf8",newline='\n') as u:
        reader = csv.DictReader(u, delimiter=',', quotechar='|' ) 
        found = False
        for row in reader:
            if row["Name"] == name:
                print("Here are the details for user {}... ".format(row["Name"]))                   
                print("Name: {}".format( row["Name"]))
                print("Age: {}".format( row["Age"]))
                print("Year Group: {}".format( row["Year Group"]))
                found = True
                break # leave for loop
        if not found:
            print("Not in users")


checkUsers("Michael Jordan")
checkUsers("Chris Cringle")
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'Michael Jordan'), ('Age', '11'), 
             ('Year Group', '7'), ('Username', 'Mic11'), ('Password', 'GetSomeHelp')])
Not in users
```

Comment: As a matter of habit, don't forget to `open()` CSV files with `newline=''` in order to support multiple-line values and - generally all text files - with an explicit `encoding` argument, to avoid silent data breakage.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it said "missing 1 required positional argument". How do I fix this?

Comment: @Tomalak  I found https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader about file object and the usage of `newline=''` but why is it needed . it only tells to use it like that?

Comment: It just comes up with "not in users" when relying on the 'user' variable being global, and when I put user in () it said that it was missing (missing 1 positional argument)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Why is it needed? I mentioned that in my comment above. It's not *needed* when the input CSV is simple, in the same way that specifying the file encoding is not *needed* when CSV matches your computer configuration's default encoding. But writing it anyway will not break anything, will make the implicit explicit ([PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) and will generally allow the `csv` module to play out its potential. So I've made a habit out of not being picky and always write those attributes when working with CSV or text.

Comment: @ErinJones I added your formatting to my example. Use a debugger on your code and step through, start with the output of `print("Not in users")` - if that is printed your error comes behind that - probably some `print( "{} bla {} blubb {}".format("a","b") ) ` where the string contains 3 placeholders but only 2 variables are supplied

Answer (score 0):

Try this?:

```
import pandas
#read csv data
stalking = pandas.read_csv('details.csv')
#Select all records from the stalking csv where Username equals the user you are looking for
user_details = stalking[stalking['Username']==user]

#Print values for each column from subset of data which only contains records where username == user
print('Name: {}'.format(user_details['Name']))
print('Age: {}'.format(user_details['Age']))
print('Year Group: {}'.format(user_details['Year Group']))
```

edit: FYI if there are multiple rows with the same username this will print all the names, ages and year groups associated with that username.

pandas makes accessing and working with csvs really easily.  Once you've done var = pandas.read_csv('somefile.csv') you can access all the values in a given column using var['col1']. Subsetting can be done by doing var[var['col1'] == 'something'], which reads as 'Select records from dataset var where the values of col1 are 'something'.

The pandas docs can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Dictreader might also be a good way to go if pandas seems a bit too complex for what you're tyring to do.